# Reel locks when reeling in then bail flips open. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: fishing, fishing-tackle, fishing-rods

The reel seems to jam when I reel it around and then if I put pressure on the reel handle, or the line, the bail flips open. I’m sure there’s something I am doing wrong. Video attached for reference. https://youtu.be/cqw7HP5Xk-c

Comment: The bail is actually flipping _closed_, which is the desired action. The problem is that there seems to be too much force required in turning the handle past the point at which the bail flips. The reel might need lubrication or adjustment. Or there could be some line or other obstruction under the spool. The spool should be easy to remove by unscrewing the drag dial on the reel's front. If you're not familiar with doing any of that or are unable to find information online for your particular model, I would suggest taking the reel to someone in your area who services fishing gear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the video provided to illustrate your issue was short, it appeared to me that spinning reel in question is a Pflueger President? But I could be wrong. I understand wanting the bail to close easily with a turn of the handle following a cast with your spinning rod/reel setup. Also I’m going to assume the same desired action is/was possible with less effort for other spinning reels you may either own or have used. However, please refer to the owner’s/user’s manual provided by the manufacturer of your spinning reel (or any spinning reel for on the matter). Within the manual under the topic of (and I’m generalizing here) “How To Cast/Use Your New Spinning Reel” there will be a disclaimer/notice advising the spinning reel‘s bail to be closed manually by hand after casting and NOT closed by turning the handle. Closing the bail by turning the handle increases wear and tear on internal gears of the reel.